# IndexOutOfBoundsException al reducir los resultados de un RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, arraylist

En la app hay una opción de preferencias con un checkbox donde se puede seleccionar para mostrar todos los resultados, o bien, no tenerlo seleccionado y mostrar solo los elementos que están marcados con un 1.

Esto funciona bien, si selecciono todo la app muestra todos los registros desde SQLite, y si no lo selecciono, muestra sólo la selección. Hasta ahí bien.

Si está configurado para mostrar todo, el RecyclerView muestra todos los registros, y luego, pulsando en cada item, puedo ir a otra actividad y mostrar el detalle, funciona correctamente.

Pero si tengo la app configurada para mostrar sólo una selección, el RecyclerView muestra los elementos adecuados, pero luego cuando intento acceder al detalle del mismo (mediante el evento setOnClicListener() me da el error indicado IndexOutOfBoundsException.

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 2

En el ejercicio tengo 4 registros

- 2 registros con el valor del campo vendido a 1
- 2 registros con el valor del campo vendido a 0

Parece que cuando configuro para mostrar sólo los registros no se actualiza la lista de elementos, y no sé cómo hacer para que se actualice dicho tamaño.

La prueba del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La clase `ListadoMotosRecyclerViewActivity`

```
public class ListadoMotosRecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<Motocicleta> listMotocicleta;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ConnectionSQLiteHelper conn;
    private Motocicleta motocicleta;
    private Preferencias preferencias;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado_motos_recycler_view);

        conn = new ConnectionSQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(), "bd_motocicletas", null, 1);
        listMotocicleta = new ArrayList<>();
        motocicleta = null;

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listadoMotosReclycerId);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        preferencias = new Preferencias(this);
        consultarListaMotocicletas();

        AdapterListarMotocicletas adapterListarMotocicletas = new AdapterListarMotocicletas(listMotocicleta);

        adapterListarMotocicletas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = listMotocicleta.get(recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getId() -1;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                irPantallaMotocicleta(position);
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterListarMotocicletas);
        conn.close();
    }

    private void irPantallaMotocicleta(int position) {
        // AQUÍ DA EL ERROR
        motocicleta = listMotocicleta.get(position);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CrearEditarMotoActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("motocicleta", motocicleta);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private void consultarListaMotocicletas() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getReadableDatabase();
        motocicleta = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;

        if (preferencias.cargarPreferencias()) {
            cursor = db.rawQuery("select id, vendido, marca, modelo, km, anyo, precio, cc, cv from " + TablaMotocicletas.TABLA_MOTOCICLETAS, null);
        } else {
            cursor = db.rawQuery("select id, vendido, marca, modelo, km, anyo, precio, cc, cv from "
                    + TablaMotocicletas.TABLA_MOTOCICLETAS
                    + " where " + TablaMotocicletas.CAMPO_VENDIDO + "=?",
                    new String[] {String.valueOf(0)});
        }

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            motocicleta = new Motocicleta();
            motocicleta.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            motocicleta.setVendido(cursor.getInt(1));
            motocicleta.setMarca(cursor.getString(2));
            motocicleta.setModelo(cursor.getString(3));
            motocicleta.setKm(cursor.getInt(4));
            motocicleta.setAnyo(cursor.getInt(5));
            motocicleta.setPrecio(cursor.getInt(6));
            motocicleta.setCc(cursor.getInt(7));
            motocicleta.setCv(cursor.getInt(8));

            listMotocicleta.add(motocicleta);
        }

        conn.close();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

El adapter correspondiente `AdapterListarMotocicletas`

```
public class AdapterListarMotocicletas extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterListarMotocicletas.ViewHolderData> implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<Motocicleta> listMotocicletas;
    private View.OnClickListener listener;

    public AdapterListarMotocicletas(ArrayList<Motocicleta> listMotocicletas) {
        this.listMotocicletas = listMotocicletas;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdapterListarMotocicletas.ViewHolderData onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_listado_motos, null, false);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        return new ViewHolderData(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterListarMotocicletas.ViewHolderData holder, int position) {
        holder.txtId.setText(listMotocicletas.get(position).getId().toString());
        if (listMotocicletas.get(position).getVendido().toString() == "1") {
            holder.imgVendido.setImageResource(R.drawable.bola_verde);
        } else {
            holder.imgVendido.setImageResource(R.drawable.bola_roja);
        }
        holder.txtMarca.setText(listMotocicletas.get(position).getMarca());
        holder.txtModelo.setText(listMotocicletas.get(position).getModelo());
        holder.txtKm.setText(listMotocicletas.get(position).getKm().toString());
        holder.txtAnyo.setText(listMotocicletas.get(position).getAnyo().toString());
        holder.txtPrecio.setText(listMotocicletas.get(position).getPrecio().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listMotocicletas.size();
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onClick(v);
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolderData extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtId, txtMarca, txtModelo, txtKm, txtAnyo, txtPrecio;
        ImageView imgVendido;

        public ViewHolderData(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
            imgVendido = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgVendido);
            txtMarca = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMarca);
            txtModelo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtModelo);
            txtKm = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtKm);
            txtAnyo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAnyo);
            txtPrecio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrecio);
        }
    }
}
```

En la actividad para mostrar el registro compruebo si `bundle` contiene algo (el objeto) y lo muestro:

```
private void cargarDatosMoto() {
    motocicleta = null;
    motocicleta = (Motocicleta) bundle.getSerializable("motocicleta");

    txtTituloMoto.setText(R.string.editar_motocicleta);
    btnCrearMotocicleta.setText(R.string.editar_motocicleta);

    for(int i= 0; i < spnMarca.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
        if(spnMarca.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString().contains(motocicleta.getMarca())) {
            spnMarca.setSelection(i);
        }
    }

    edtModelo.setText(motocicleta.getModelo());
    edtAnyo.setText(motocicleta.getAnyo().toString());
    edtKm.setText(motocicleta.getAnyo().toString());
    edtCC.setText(motocicleta.getCc().toString());
    edtCV.setText(motocicleta.getCv().toString());
    edtPrecio.setText(motocicleta.getPrecio().toString());

    if (motocicleta.getVendido() == 1) {
        swtVendido.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Deberías iniciar tu actividad desde el adaptador ya que este te ofrece la posición del elemento

Comment: ¿Eso solventaría el problema @FranqoBalsamo? ¿Y cómo lo hago, alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bien, siguiendo con tu adaptador, puedes modificarlo para que funcione desde aquí tu evento para abrir una nueva actividad:

```
   public class AdapterListarMotocicletas extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterListarMotocicletas.ViewHolderData>  {

    private ArrayList<Motocicleta> listMotocicletas;
    private Context context;

    public AdapterListarMotocicletas(ArrayList<Motocicleta> listMotocicletas, Context context) {
        this.listMotocicletas = listMotocicletas;
        this.context = context ;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdapterListarMotocicletas.ViewHolderData onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_listado_motos, null, false);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        return new ViewHolderData(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterListarMotocicletas.ViewHolderData holder, int position) {
        holder.txtId.setText(listMotocicletas.get(position).getId().toString());
        if (listMotocicletas.get(position).getVendido().toString() == "1") {
            holder.imgVendido.setImageResource(R.drawable.bola_verde);
        } else {
            holder.imgVendido.setImageResource(R.drawable.bola_roja);
        }
        holder.txtMarca.setText(listMotocicletas.get(position).getMarca());
        holder.txtModelo.setText(listMotocicletas.get(position).getModelo());
        holder.txtKm.setText(listMotocicletas.get(position).getKm().toString());
        holder.txtAnyo.setText(listMotocicletas.get(position).getAnyo().toString());
        holder.txtPrecio.setText(listMotocicletas.get(position).getPrecio().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listMotocicletas.size();

    public class ViewHolderData extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{ //implementa tu click aquí

        TextView txtId, txtMarca, txtModelo, txtKm, txtAnyo, txtPrecio;
        ImageView imgVendido;

        public ViewHolderData(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
            imgVendido = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgVendido);
            txtMarca = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMarca);
            txtModelo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtModelo);
            txtKm = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtKm);
            txtAnyo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAnyo);
            txtPrecio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrecio);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this); lo declaramos aquí
        }
         
         //aquí haremos el evento
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
            int itemPosition = getAdapterPosition(); //gracias a esto podremos saber la posición del elemento clickeado
            Motocicleta motocicleta = motocicleta = listMotocicleta.get(itemPosition );
            Intent i = new Intent(context, CrearEditarMotoActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("motocicleta", motocicleta);
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);


         }
     }
  }
```

Y tu `onCreate()`, quedará así:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado_motos_recycler_view);

    conn = new ConnectionSQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(), "bd_motocicletas", null, 1);
    listMotocicleta = new ArrayList<>();
    motocicleta = null;

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listadoMotosReclycerId);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    preferencias = new Preferencias(this);
    consultarListaMotocicletas();

    AdapterListarMotocicletas adapterListarMotocicletas = new AdapterListarMotocicletas(listMotocicleta, getContext());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterListarMotocicletas);
    conn.close();
}
```

Comment: Franqo, ¡muchísimas gracias por tu implementación! a parte de funcionar veo que incluso es más fácil de hacer que lo que hice yo

Comment: ¡Que bueno que te haya servido!